# MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

I have following code in my DBclass.

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse(date);

DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dateDb = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
```

If I get the input and try to print it then the ouput I get is this one :

```
input date :: 11/24/2014
parse form is :: Mon Nov 24 00:00:00 EST 2014
```

I want to put this value in database and I get `com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '' for columnn etc`

Is it because of simple date format? how do I truncate it to only the date(I don't want hours-mins-secs)?

Comment: As stated by the message `''` (i.e. empty string) is not a correct date